# Grub making a weird error

Tags: linux, grub, arch-linux

I recently installed Arch Linux but when I went to boot it wouldn't. I then switched on legacy mode and it did boot but the screen just said GRUB with a flashing underscore and wouldn't do anything else no matter what I did.

It may be that, because `grub-install` would not install properly with default settings, I installed it with `--target=i386-pc` but I tried using the boot CD to download the 64 bit version but it wouldn't let me remount the boot drive.

I would prefer not to reformat the drive but I will do it if I have to.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a few EFI bios will have a problem with trying to legacy boot, of which you may have to explicitly turn on or off and the same applies with secure boot.

You probably have an EFI based boot loader on your target machine unless it is older. This means you will want to install as EFI and not MBR which is what the i386 target will try for and what was used for the past few decades. EFI is new in widespread use in the last few years and it is a more advanced type of bootloader primarily for x86_64 machines. In short, you have a VFAT or EXT2 partition as an EFI partition which will have the .efi files for your bootloaders on it, which are programmed to do the proper bootloading. You can select which one is used from the bios although you can also have one chainload another one. The command `lsblk` will list block devices and should give you an idea which one it is. You may have another boot partition of any given file system format that grub understands which is normally mounted at `/boot` or it may be your primary root partition. The `.efi` loader may use that partition to hold your kernel and `initrd` image among other things.

You probably want to boot arch linux and then chroot to your primary Linux root partition:

Example:

```
lsblk
mkdir /mnt/arch
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/arch
mount -t proc none /mnt/arch/proc
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/arch/sys
mount --make-rslave /mnt/arch/sys 
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/arch/dev
mount --make-rslave /mnt/arch/dev
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/arch/boot
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/arch/boot/efi
chroot /mnt/arch
```

Where the dev device nodes correspond to what you found in `lsblk` output.

This is the typical `chroot` preamble in Linux for chrooting into the primary installation from boot media. After you chroot you should have a distribution just as usable as if you had booted into it unless you have anything else that needs mounted.

With this information you should be able to proceed to the following two links:

- [Arch Linux Grub Installation Documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB)
- [Arch Linux EFI Examples](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/EFI_examples)

Although a typical EFI grub installation is usually as easy as so:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader id=grub
```

Note that at times the commands may be `grub2-mkconfig` and `grub2-install` depending on the Linux variant.